# How to use string instead of file for XSLT.Load and XSLT.Transform method?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I am using http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/XSLT.aspx to Convert comma delimited data (CSV) to XML using XSLT template.

It uses the foll. 2 lines of .NET code:

```
 XSLT.Load(mstrInputXSLTFile, resolver);
 XSLT.Transform(mstrInputCSVFile, mstrOutputXMLFile, resolver);
```

I am looking for a way in which I can use the string contents (contents of the XSLT, CSV file) instead of files in above 2 methods.. Any help will be usefull.

I am planning to implement this logic in a WCF webservice which will receive the csv string. If there is no workaround then I will have to create temp files based on the values of csv and xsl received. Process the conversion of csv to xml on the server and return the xml output to the client. Then delete the files created above.

Comment: Why do you use the obsolete `XslTransform` and not `XslCompiledTransform`?

Comment: Both of them do not support xslt 2.0. What is the plus of using the XslCompiledTransform?

Comment: XslCompiledTransform is Microsoft's XSLT processor in the .NET framework since .NET 2.0. It should have better performance than XslTransform and better standards compliance. It is true however that Microsoft does not offer an XSLT 2.0 processor. For that you need a third party solution like XmlPrime or the .NET version of Saxon.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/antosha/archive/2006/07/16/xslcompiledtransform-slower-than-xsltransform.aspx Says the newer option may be significantly slower

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the input from a string then create an `XmlReader` over a `StringReader` over your string e.g.

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();

using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(stringVar))
{
  using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
  {
    proc.Load(xr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no suitable method in [XslTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform(v=vs.110).aspx) which does what you want.

However, you could write your own [extensions methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx) (I would call them `Parse..`), which take content as string, create files in the temporary directory, and load/transform them by the suitable methods.